# how to make a dot plot based on each column and highlight the beginning and the end

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(Number = 1:23, Value1 = c(0.054830335, 1.19531842, 
3.27820329, 1.03530176, 5.77430976, 3.72944, -0.683513395, 0.029550239, 
2.487922644, 0.533448117, 0.098825565, -1.089022938, 2.301631235, 
-0.095666867, -1.359480317, -1.359480317, 1.089441628, 3.307589929, 
4.67838434, 3.562761178, 2.630726653, 1.795107015, 2.616255192
), Value2 = c(-0.296874921, 1.491747294, 2.951219257, 1.258677675, 
-8.68096591, 3.361029751, -1.824459195, -1.445827538, 1.889631269, 
-15.47774216, 3.085461276, -1.078286963, 0.948056999, -2.109354753, 
-1.36703068, -1.36703068, 1.074642842, 2.945589842, 3.757911793, 
2.765225717, 2.44452491, 1.784451022, 1.158493893)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
```

I am trying to make a dot plot (one color for the Value1 vrsus number) and one with Value2 versus Number. Then show the first 5 values in bigger size and the bottom 5 in bigger size

I tried to plot it like this

```
df$Number <- factor(df$Number, levels = paste0("D", 1:23), ordered = TRUE)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Value1, y=Value2, color= Number)) + 
  geom_text()+
  theme_classic()
```

I can plot one of them like this

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Number, y = Value1))+
  geom_point()
```

when it comes to have the second one on the same plot, kinda fuzzy.

I can put them together in this way

```
# wide to long format
plotDf <- gather(df, Group, Myvalue, -1)
# plot
ggplot(plotDf, aes(Number, Myvalue, col = Group)) +
  geom_point()
```

I still don't know how to show the first 5 values in bigger size and last 5 values in bigger size

The first 5 and the last 5 I mean these ones

```
 df
       Number      Value1      Value2
    1       1  0.05483034  -0.2968749
    2       2  1.19531842   1.4917473
    3       3  3.27820329   2.9512193
    4       4  1.03530176   1.2586777
    5       5  5.77430976  -8.6809659
    6       6  3.72944000   3.3610298
    7       7 -0.68351339  -1.8244592
    8       8  0.02955024  -1.4458275
    9       9  2.48792264   1.8896313
    10     10  0.53344812 -15.4777422
    11     11  0.09882557   3.0854613
    12     12 -1.08902294  -1.0782870
    13     13  2.30163123   0.9480570
    14     14 -0.09566687  -2.1093548
    15     15 -1.35948032  -1.3670307
    16     16 -1.35948032  -1.3670307
    17     17  1.08944163   1.0746428
    18     18  3.30758993   2.9455898
    19     19  4.67838434   3.7579118
    20     20  3.56276118   2.7652257
    21     21  2.63072665   2.4445249
    22     22  1.79510701   1.7844510
    23     23  2.61625519   1.1584939
```

These are the first 5

```
1       1        0.05483034  -0.2968749
        2       2  1.19531842   1.4917473
        3       3  3.27820329   2.9512193
        4       4  1.03530176   1.2586777
        5       5  5.77430976  -8.6809659
```

and these are the last 5

```
 19     19  4.67838434   3.7579118
    20     20  3.56276118   2.7652257
    21     21  2.63072665   2.4445249
    22     22  1.79510701   1.7844510
    23     23  2.61625519   1.1584939
```

Comment: You say dotplot but you use `geom_text`, and with two variables `treatment` and `replicate` that we don't have.

Comment: @r2evans I correct it , I am going to add also a function that I could plot one of them but not two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the original data (without `factor`):

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Number, Value1, size = (Number <= 5 | Number > 18))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(y=Value2)) +
  scale_size_manual(name = NULL, values = c("TRUE" = 2, "FALSE"  = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(z) do.call(seq, as.list(round(z,0))))
```

[image: ggplot2]

Because using a logical condition to determine `size=`, the manual values assigned to it need to correspond to character versions of the various values observed, which are of course `TRUE` and `FALSE` logicals into `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"`. My choice of `2` and `0.5` is arbitrary.

Feel free to name the legend better with `name="some name"` if desired. If you want no legend (which makes sense), you can use

```r
... +
  scale_size_manual(guide = "none", values = c("TRUE" = 2, "FALSE"  = 0.5))
```

instead.

Another alternative, in case you want to make distinct the dots by which `Value#` they are, is to melt the data into a long format before plotting.

```r
ggplot(reshape2::melt(df, "Number"),
       aes(Number, value, color = variable,
           size = (Number <= 5 | Number >= 18))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_manual(guide = "none", values = c("TRUE" = 2, "FALSE" = 0.5))
```

[image: ggplot2 with colored points for each value1 and value2]

One can use `tidyr::pivot_longer` or `data.table::melt` with similar results, see [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272).